# Camera following an objects rotation

Tags: camera, three.js

I'm trying to get a 'chase' camera working on an object.

I've found an example that doe exactly what I want, however it is aimed at r49:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Chase-Camera.html

I've attempted to update it to the new rotation methods as follows:

`var rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(rotateAngle);
   cube.matrix.multiplySelf(rotation_matrix);
   cube.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix(cube.matrix);`

This seems to work fine for the object, however the camera doesn't follow in the same way. I've put up a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SSEDs/

(Press A and D to rotate)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, forgot to accept on old questions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add the camera as a child of the cube. Not only does it work, but the math is a lot simpler.

```
cube.add( camera );
```

Comment: But, when the mesh rotates so does the camera. What if we only wanted to rotate the mesh itself?

Comment: @majidarif `scene.add( group ); group.add( mesh ); group.add( offset ); offset.add( camera );` `group.position` controls the mesh's and camera's position. `mesh.rotation` controls the mesh`s rotation.