# Three.js TranslateX or Y causes rotation but I just want it to move straight along the axis

Tags: jquery, css, three.js

I'm using Three.js and TrackballControls to create a 3D scene.

I created a new PerspectiveCamera

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
```

I added a few buttons for zoom in, out, left, right etc... Here is the code for zoom in which is working good:

```
var button = document.getElementById( 'ctrlin' );
button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

    camera.translateZ( -100 );

}, false );
```

However when I try "camera.translateY" or "camera.translateX" my camera rotates.

**I just want it to move along the straight axis.**

I realize this could have to do with a locked gimbal setting but I'm unsure how to fix this.

Would it be better to move the object or the camera? How would I do either on a straight X or Y axis?

Answer (score 1):

If you move the camera along the X-axis then you also have to move the target of the camera the same distance along the X-axis otherwise it rotates, because it continues to look at the same point.

See if that can help you out solving the issue.

Another solution could be to add both the camera and the target into a container object and start moving the object around :)

**EDIT:**

An example of the last solution including a can be found [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12998738/1697459)

Comment: I still have not found an answer to this. What you propose does not include code to move the camera along an x or y axis while moving the target... Do you have any examples? Thanks

Comment: There are lots of examples for this on StackOverflow. I added a link to one of them that has a Fiddle to my answer.